# Apache Solr. No records fetched for MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, solr

I am trying to fetch MS SQL data through Solr on my local machine. I am able to create connecting but it fetches 0 records. Loading the library looks fine.

Solr Config:

```
<lib dir="../../../contrib/dataimporthandler/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-dataimporthandler-.*\.jar" />
<lib dir="C:\Users\mereddda\Downloads\sqljdbc_6.0.8112.200_enu (1)\sqljdbc_6.0\enu\jre8\sqljdbc42.jar"/>
```

Added the path of the lib  directly as well.
Data- Config:

```
<dataConfig>
  <dataSource type="JdbcDataSource" 
          driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" 
       url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=locsh_ControlledVocabulary_Dev"   
          user="AD\mereddda" 
          password=""/>
  <document>
    <entity name="product"  
      pk="id"
    query="select id,name from products"
    deltaImportQuery="SELECT id,name from products WHERE id='${dih.delta.id}'"
       deltaQuery="SELECT id FROM products  WHERE updated_at > '${dih.last_index_time}'"
  >
       <field column="id" name="id"/>
      <field column="name" name="name"/>       
    </entity>
  </document>
</dataConfig>
```

Comment: Assuming thatal

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all the defined parameters are OK, you are getting the connection, the query is not raising any issue, you are properly issuing a full import command to Solr, then the answer you're looking for is in the solr logs. Shooting in the dark, something like "missing mandatory field", "missing unique key" or "malformed field value".

Last but not least, I Don't know your commit policy: if you don't issue, explicitly or implicitly a commit command, no change will be visible

Comment: Thanks for reply. When I checked the log I found. JDBC is not loading."Couldn't add files from C:\Users\mereddda\Downloads\solr-7.3.0\solr-7.3.0\server\solr\wiki1\..\..\contrib\dataimporthandler\lib filtered by .*\.jar to classpath: C:\Users\mereddda\Downloads\solr-7.3.0\solr-7.3.0\server\solr\wiki1\..\..\contrib\dataimporthandler\lib"  But i have added the jar properly.

Comment: Any one please help me on this. I am not at all able to find this issue. As per my knowledge everything is in place. Still do not know why I am getting this issue.